Derivation of Continuity Equation for an Incompressible flow
Good day guys,
I was playing around with the following form of the continuity equation:
$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} - \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{v}) = 0 $$
For an incompressible fluid: $\frac{D\rho}{Dt} = 0$ which basically denotes,
$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = - (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\rho$.
Substituting back into the continuity equation,
$$ - (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\rho - \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{v}) = 0$$
or
$$ - (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\rho = \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{v})$$
I fail to see how I can reduce this equation to the usual continuity euqation for an incompressible flow:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$$

For an arbitrary scalar function $f$ and vector field $\vec v$ we have the multi-dimensional analog of the product rule for derivatives
$$\nabla\cdot(f\vec v)=(\nabla f)\cdot\vec v + f\nabla\cdot v$$
That, and correcting a sign error in your first equation, gives the result.

Thank you! By the way, is $(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \rho  = (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla \rho) $

If I had to interpret the left hand side, my interpretation would be the right hand side.

Awesome, thank you! I just have one more question:
The sign on my first equation is a result of defining the mass rate of a CV as $\dot{m_{cv}} = \dot{m_{out}} - \dot{m_{in}}$, I can fix my workings by redefining it as $\dot{m_{cv}} = \dot{m_{in}} - \dot{m_{out}}$. Would there be a way to play around with my other equations to get to the same result using my initial definition (out - in)?

Think of the physics. If the outflow is larger than the inflow (positive divergence), then the local density will decrease not increase.
